# expo-av local audio file not playing in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mobile-application

I think i've checked every single thread on the internet to try and find this solution, my mind is about to explode.

I've followed the docs and other people's answers and I can't seem to get this audio file to play. I've tried installing earlier versions of expo-asset and expo-av and still no luck. I was getting an error that the packaged weren't compatible with the latest version of Expo. I didn't try installing earlier versions of Expo though I think it's bullsh*t that I'd have to do that to get this work.

Console logs are all working as expected, no error logs, its just the damn audio file wont play when i press the button.

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const WordsList = ({ route }) => {

    const [sound, setSound] = useState();

    async function playSound() {
      console.log('Loading Sound')
      try {
          const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            require('./uno.mp3'),
            { shouldPlay: true,}
            );
            
            setSound(sound);
            console.log('Playing Sound');
            await sound.playAsync();

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      return sound
        ? () => {
            console.log('Unloading Sound');
            sound.unloadAsync();
          }
        : undefined;
    }, [sound]);
    
    // Params passed in from wordsCategories.js SearchComponent
    const {category, words} = route.params;

    return (
            <View>       
                <FlatList 
                data={words}
                renderItem={({item}) => <RenderCardItem item={item}/>}
                />
                <Button title='play sound' onPress={playSound} />
            </View>
    )
}

export default WordsList
```

dependencies:

```
"expo": "^46.0.2",
"expo-asset": "~8.6.3",
"expo-av": "~12.0.4",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you confirm that `require('./uno.mp3')` path and file name are correct. and file is working

Comment: Yeah so the file works fine on my computer., even in VSCode when I click the file directly, it works. The path was originally in another folder and I moved it directly into the same folder as the component just to see if I was making a stupid mistake with the path and its still the same.

Comment: are you logging all the console.logs. so function is being called but sound is not plating?

Comment: Yes. All statements are being logged to the console with no problem.
I went on the expo docs for expo-av and went into one of the expo snacks. The sounds don't even play there. There's a toast message as soon as you start up the snack with the following message:

The requested Expo version is not yet supported. We have downgraded the Expo version to 47.0.0.
You might need to do some manual changes to make the Snack work correctly.
I even tried installing my expo version to 47.0.0 to see if that was the problem but still not working.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

Comment: I even downloaded a different audio file from someone else's guide on how to play audio in react native expo and there sound isn't working either.

Comment: Another update. Real strange -- With the snack, I just used my own mobile device to scan the QR code and test the snack on my iPhone and the sound is playing! The sound also works in web view.  If i try the iOS and Android simulators in the snack, sound doesn't play.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to waste people's time but i found the solution and its ridiculous.

The volume on the simulator was all the way down. Even if you pump the volume up full blast on your computer, it wont sync with the volume on the simulator so make sure you actually turn the volume up with the buttons on the simulator.

Comment: thanks a lot, save me some time.
For anyone who might have a similar issue also check that 'virtual microphone uses host audio input' from the simulator settings